# Laravel Pre-Flight CORS

Tags: php, laravel, cors, preflight

I have a problem with Laravel CORS. I've installed `barryvdh/laravel-cors` bundle with the following configuration file:

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' => ['PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 0,
```

I've even added following lines to my `AppServiceProfider.php` file

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,X-CSRF-TOKEN');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE');
```

And I still can not make PUT request on Firefox. I'm getting "Same Origin Policy" error - method not found in CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods".

What's weird: as you can see, I set Allow-Methods header to `POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE`, but every browser says that it's set to `*`:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,X-CSRF-TOKEN
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

What's even weirder - when I make the same request in Postman, headers look fine:

```
access-control-allow-headers →Authorization,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,XCSRF-TOKEN
access-control-allow-methods →POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE
```

What's wrong? Is laravel handling Pre-flight requests different?

Comment: You can edit .htaccess for that not need to use any library

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I solved it by setting headers in .htaccess file as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   #...... other settings here

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "access_token, x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cookie, Referer"
</IfModule>
```